# What is the space of weakly holomorphic modular forms of weight $\frac12$?

Tags: modular-forms, modular-function, elliptic-modular-form

What is the space of weakly holomorphic modular forms of weight $\frac12$ for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$?

My thoughts as of yet: The derivative $j_l:=(j^l)'$ of the $j$-invariant for $l\in\mathbb N$ is a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight $2$. So $j_l \, /\eta^{3}$ is a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight $\frac12$ for any $l\in\mathbb N$. Since
$$ (j^l)'=-2\pi i\,  l \, j^l \frac{E_6}{E_4}$$
and $\Delta\sim \eta^{24}$, we can generalise this to any form $f_{klm}=E_4^k E_6^l \eta^m$, which has weight $\frac12$ if $4k+6l+\frac m2=\frac12$, for $k,l\geq 0$.

- Are there other such forms?
- Can we find such forms given more constraints, such as the asymptotics for $\tau\to i\infty$? I'm in particular interested in weakly  holomorphic modular forms $f$ of weight $\frac12$ which behave as $f(\tau)=q^{-\frac18}+...$ as $\tau\to i\infty$. Does such a modular form even exist?

Comment: Can you remind us what is a weakly modular form of weight $1/2$ for the full modular group?

Comment: I would define a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight $k$ as a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb H\to \mathbb C$ that satisfies $f(\gamma\tau)=\epsilon(a,b,c,d)(c\tau+d)^k f(\tau)$ for all $\gamma\in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, for some $\epsilon$ with  $|\epsilon(a,b,c,d)|=1$. I assume your question suggests that this definition is not well-defined for $k=\frac12$?

Comment: And by weakly holomorphic I require that $f$ is holomorphic but can be meromorphic at the cusp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G  = [PSL_2(\Bbb{Z}),PSL_2(\Bbb{Z})]$ the commutator subgroup of the modular group, it is known to be a level $12$ congruence subgroup. Let $X_G=G\backslash\Bbb{H}^*$ its modular curve. If $f$ satisfies your definition of weight $1/2$ modular then $\forall \gamma\in PSL_2(\Bbb{Z}), f/\eta(\gamma z)= \psi(\gamma) f/\eta(z)$. Check that $\psi(\gamma\gamma') = \psi(\gamma)\psi(\gamma')$ so $\psi$ is a character $PSL_2(\Bbb{Z})\to \Bbb{C}^*$.

So $G\subset \ker(\psi)$ and $f/\eta\in \Bbb{C}(X_G)$.

Next $\Bbb{C}(X_G)/\Bbb{C}(j)$ is Galois with Galois group $ PSL_2(\Bbb{Z})^{ab} \cong \Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$. Let $\chi$ be $\eta^2$'s order $12$ character given in [example  2.5](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf).

Being a degree $12$ cyclic extension by Kummer theory $\Bbb{C}(X_G) =\Bbb{C}(j)(h)$ with $h^{12}\in \Bbb{C}(j)$ which is such that $h(\gamma z) = \chi^k(\gamma) h( z)$ for all $\gamma\in PSL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ and for some $\gcd(k,12)=1$.

We get $$\Bbb{C}(X_G) = \bigoplus_{m=0}^{11}  h^m\Bbb{C}(j)$$
a direct sum of eigenspaces of a generator of $PSL_2(\Bbb{Z})^{ab}$.

Let $I_m = \{ u(j) \in \Bbb{C}(j)$, $u(j) h^m$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{H}\}$. It is a $\Bbb{C}[j]$ submodule of $\Bbb{C}(j)$ so $I_m=v_m(j) \Bbb{C}[j]$ for some $v_m(j)\in \Bbb{C}(j)$ that you'll find from the zeros/poles of $h$.

$f/\eta$ is in one of the eigenspaces $\Bbb{C}(j) h^m$, and being holomorphic on $\Bbb{H}$ we get $f/\eta \in h^m I_m$. ie. your space is $$\bigcup_{m=0}^{11} \eta h^m v_m(j) \Bbb{C}[j] $$

Comment: Thank you! Could you give an example for $h$? And does the result essentially mean that $\eta^2$ is the "only" weight 1 modular form for $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ since its order 12 character is unique?

Comment: I would ask on mathoverflow for some $h$ with known zeros poles. $h$ shall be a sum/product of $j(Az)$ with $\det(A)=12$ but the calculation will be a headache and it is unclear if it will be easy to locate its zeros/poles. The weight 1 weakly modular forms such that $f(\gamma z) = \psi(\gamma) f(z)$ are found with the same method and you'll be able to check which ones have no poles at the cusps.